# How to get Custom object in java spring?

Tags: spring, kotlin, controller

I'm using java spring for my server.

My question is how can I get custom object through the controller.

Example for what I mean:

I know I can do that by doing two functions:

```
      @RequestMapping(
        path = arrayOf("getObject", "getObject/"),
        method = arrayOf(RequestMethod.GET))
open fun getRecord1(@RequestBody data: CustomObjectOption1): ResponseEntity<*> {
    return ResponseEntity<Any>(data.name,HttpStatus.OK)

}

     @RequestMapping(
        path = arrayOf("getObject", "getObject/"),
        method = arrayOf(RequestMethod.GET))
open fun getRecord2(@RequestBody data: CustomObjectOption2): ResponseEntity<*> {
    return ResponseEntity<Any>(data.number,HttpStatus.OK)

}
```

but I want to do it by only one endpoint:

```
 @RequestMapping(
        path = arrayOf("getObject", "getObject/"),
        method = arrayOf(RequestMethod.GET))
open fun getRecord(@RequestBody data: CustomObjectOption): ResponseEntity<*> {

  if(data instance option1)
    return ResponseEntity<Any>(data.name,HttpStatus.OK)
```

else
      return ResponseEntity(data.number,HttpStatus.OK)
else
    }

such that the object can be like this:

option 1:

```
  public class CustomObject {

      private String name;
      private Long id;

   }
```

or option 2:

```
     public class CustomObject {

      private List<Integer> number;
      private List<Long> count;

   }
```

Is that possible to do that in java spring?

The only solution I was thinking is to use **inheritance** but I would like to know if there's different way...

Thank you for the help

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @JBNizet can you tell me what you don't understand? in general I'm trying to pass to the controller the same object but I want that this object could be from type A or from type B

Comment: Just don't. There is no good reason to send two completely different objects to the same resource. Create two different controller (or controller methods), doing two different things, and accepting two different types of objects.

Comment: Also, using GET to send a request body doesn't make any sense. GET requests don't have a body.

Answer (score 0):

Just as you have written, you can do it just like that:

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public void method(@RequestBody YourCustomClass body)
```

`YourCustomClass` can be either option 1 or option 2.

And that's all :)

Comment: the only problem that you can't create to different objects with the same name in java... so YourCustomClass can be only one of the option. how can I know if its option 1 or 2?

Comment: Then do it like this:
`@RequestBody Object body`
`if(body instance of com.example.class.CustomClass){} else if (body instance of com.example.another.class.CustomClass){}`

Comment: its almost fine. the problem here that java recognize the 'body' as list of key and value like a Jason... what do you recommenced to fix that?

Comment: As far as I know if you give it the proper Json it should map it to Object without any problem. Just add the annotation `@RestController` for the whole controller class

Comment: I know how to map to object but not on the way that you recommends. it not working this way, im sure there is different way to do it...